# How to configure managed switch

Tags: networking, cisco, switch

The work environment is shown below. I want to install two new managed switches (cisco SG250-8) for the ones shown in green. I configuered the switches with one vlan and gave them the ip address 192.168.2.82 and 192.168.2.83 (subnet /24). I set the dns of the switches to the dc (192.168.2.3).

However, if I put them in place, I cannot connect to the internet from the clients. I'm not sure what other information is needed, but I would be happy to provide it.

Edit 22.12.18:

If I put the switch to the second branch (192.168.2.10 aso), the clients are able to connect to the internet. If I put it in the first branch, the clients  are no longer able to conncet to the internet. A ping from the switch to 8.8.8.8 never works.

[image]

Comment: Maybe consider not daisy chaining the switches and connect them to the firewall directly or put a distribution switch between the firewall and the access switches.

Answer (score 1):

First check that you have reach-ability to the internet by direct connection from the router to a PC. simultaneously check from Firewall, & Each switches. Hope 192.168.2.0/24 is ur LAN zone. check reach-ability from the lan to their gateway[192.168.2.82 and .83(expecting)]. Check trunking configuration between the two switches and allowed Vlan types.If every thing is ok then go for the route to 192.168.1.0 network for this lan zone.And finally Check the firewall policy for the lane zone to reach to the internet.